# No sound device detected

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTE on a new Lenovo E470 machine. No sound device is detected, I mean:

[image]

And similarly, no input device is detected. Some information that may be helpful:
`aplay -l` returns

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Anyhow, an audio device exists: `sudo lspci -v`returns (among other things)

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 505b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at f4420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at f4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

I tried to force the reload of alsa: `sudo alsa force-reload` returns

```
Terminating processes: 10509 (failed: processes still using sound devices: 30977(pulseaudio)).
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
```

Listing sinks in pacmd: `pacmd`

```
Welcome to PulseAudio 8.0! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> list-sinks

1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9950
    volume: front-left: 53740 /  82% / -5.17 dB,   front-right: 53740 /  82% / -5.17 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 370.83 ms
    max request: 64 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf4420000 irq 126"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Kabylake HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:8086280b,17aa505b,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
```

I should mention that I haven't been able to produce any sound on this machine beforehand.

Thank you in advance for your time, and please let me know if I can give some more useful information.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I realized I forgot to try to troubleshoot pulseaudio, as was possibly suggested by the reaction to `sudo alsa force-reload`. According to [the pulseaudio page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio), I run

`rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k`

and I rebooted. Now it works! :)

Comment: A reboot was not necessary for me. "pulseaudio" was started automatically in kubuntu 14.04. If it doesn't start, do "pulseaudio --start".

Comment: My `/etc/pulse/default.pa` had some errors because I was loading uninstalled modules. To troubelshoot, I typed `pulseaudio` in the console and was presented with error messages stating the missing modules

Comment: I wish this simple solution worked, but unfortunately, it did not :(

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and it turned out because I was logged into gdm using root and pulseaudio does not start correctly in this case but if you run the following command it works correctly:

```
pulseaudio -D
```

Comment: my kubuntu laptop was not finding audio devices. that command worked. you need to add sudo though, sudo pulseaudio -D

Comment: This works to find my headphones, but if I remove the headphones, I have to run the command every time I plug back in. Is there no way for Ubuntu to just auto-detect new audio inputs? Since it's a daemon, i figured it would but it doesn't. Maybe it's a pulseaudio bug?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the number of inotify watches fixed this for me.

Following guidance at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Daemon_startup_failed

`pulseaudio -v` gave an error:

> E: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: You apparently ran out of
>   inotify watches, probably because Tracker/Beagle took them all away. I
>   wished people would do their homework first and fix inotify before
>   using it for watching whole directory trees which is something the
>   current inotify is certainly not useful for. Please make sure to drop
>   the Tracker/Beagle guys a line complaining about their broken use of
>   inotify.

Adding a line to `etc/sysctl.conf` fixed this:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` from the linked to doc did the trick for me. I did set `max_user_watches` before that, but I don't know if that contributed.