# No sound when starting Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a certain problem.
Whenever I start Ubuntu the sound does not work, whatever the output device. It happens in all applications and websites, so I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the sound driver. In order for me to have audio, I have to unplug the device and plug it in again.
This started happening after an update, which had also messed up my graphics (which I now have fixed).

EDIT: I tried uninstalling alsa and pulseaudio, then reinstalled alsa. Now my problem has been fixed, but another one has occured: I cannot reinstall pulseaudio, meaning I have no access to sound settings and my audio card seems to not be recognized.

The error message I get when installing pulseaudio is:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio
 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12 is to be installed
              Depends: pulseaudio-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: rtkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems my problem has been fixed. I was subscribed to security-only package updates. When changed this setting, I just needed to upgrade the packages and pulseaudio was automatically redownloaded. For my initial issue, I ran this command:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

After that I rebooted and audio is perfectly recognized from all ports.

(I found the above command in this post: [No sound device detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882198/no-sound-device-detected?rq=1) )